# using annotations and getting hibernate.cfg.xml file not found

Tags: hibernate

i am using hibernate annotations in my entity class hence im not using an hibernate.cfg.xml file but it is throwing org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found exception when i try to generate the response. any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I guess this questions is only a missunderstanding basic hibernate knowlegde. When you use Spring Hibernate you need a essential hibernate.cfg.xml inside your project where you add the hibernate ORM connection params.
This is a base example of cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:"database/url/ip/"</property>
        <property name="connection.username">"userlog"</property>
        <property name="connection.password">"psw"</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Mapping files will go here.... -->
        <mapping resource="xml mapping"/>
        <mapping class="class mapping"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I hope this is usefull.